# Создание цветовых схем c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Доброго времени суток.
Хотелось бы узнать как правильно создавать цветовые схемы для приложения.
Может какой то отдельный конфиг или через *.setting в Properties.

Чтобы менять цвет шрифта во всем приложение. Цвет окна, рамок и так далее

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы делал так:

1. Определил наборы цветов, которые будут кастомизироваться.
2. Положил бы в приложение набор `ResourceDictionary`, по одному для каждого набора, в котором бы определил нужные цвета.
3. В UI ссылался бы на нужные цвета через `DynamicResource`.
4. Далее имеет смысл написать небольшой скин-менеджер, который будет

   - знать все схемы
   - предоставлять выбор схемы по имени
   - при выборе схемы находить нужны `ResourceDictionary` и подключать его как `MergedDictionary` в `Application.Resources`.
5. Выбранную схему можно положить в `Properties.Settings`, и в начале работы программы загружать её через менеджер.